# python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I have a mac and I am starting to work on django. When I try to make a project on the terminal by writing

```
python django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

I get this error

```
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

While I was looking around for help, one solution suggested to write type django-admin.py to get the location of django-admin.py and use that.

So when I type

```
python /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

my project is created.

Can anyone tell my why I need to do this and why I can't write just django-admin.py? Also is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're confusing two ways of referring to an executable file.

`/usr/local/bin` is in your path, and `django-admin.py` is marked as executable, so you can refer to it without the initial `python`:

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

When you start with `python`, that is saying "start Python with the script at this path". So, you need to pass the full path, if the script you're trying to start isn't in your current directory.

Comment: In windows, using django-admin.py would try to open the python script for editting.

Answer (score 4):

`python django-admin.py` - Python execute file `django-admin.py` in the **current working directory**.

If you add `/usr/local/bin` into the `PATH` environment variable, you can just issue `django-admin.py` instead of `python /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`.

1. Check whether PATH contains `/usr/local/bin`

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```
2. If there's no `/usr/local/bin` in the variable, add that:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin  # sh, ksh, bash, ..

   set path = ($path /usr/local/bin) # csh
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Use `django-admin.py startproject`  without the python.

You don't need to use python with the `django-admin.py startproject`, it should work from any directory. Only on windows you need to specify the full path.

`django` runs the `admin` script from the `python interpreter` in your `path`.

Answer (score 2):

For windows users, just do `django-admin startproject myproject` to use the django-admin.exe tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a different python script. Adding the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))
`#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of the script and having it my path did the trick and allowed me to call it directly as in `script.py` rather than `python full/path/2script/script.py`

Answer (score 0):

Go to /usr/local/bin and change the permission of 'django-admin.py' as non executable then everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I did check my /usr/local/bin but django-admin was missing instead it was in /usr/bin.

Later I tried below commands by executing the command in the workspace directory and it created projected for me.

**python /usr/bin/django-admin startproject projectname**

**/usr/bin/django-admin startproject projectname**

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

> python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

**Cause:** We get this error when we write python code in notepad & saving it as .py extension. But command line will treats it as `.py.txt`

**Solution:** Just type python and drag the above file into the cmd prompt & then press enter.

Then sure u get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this django-admin.py startproject youproname

i also got the same problem when i installed django in my ubuntu just use the above one it will definately work