# Django Start project not working after install

Tags: django, macos, terminal

The django project will not create. I keep getting this same error, please help. I am not sure what else can be done.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: I am using Pythin 3.8 and Dyango 3.0.3

Comment: I also verified all things were installed

Comment: Is Django listed when you run `pip freeze`?

Comment: How did you install Django? What commands did you run to install Django?

Comment: Try using `django-admin` (without `.py`).

Comment: I treid this and it also didnt work

Comment: python3 /Users/fatgezimbela/Desktop/ django-admin.py startproject wisdompets
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/Users/fatgezimbela/Desktop/'

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Flux in your comment, use django-admin to start your project.

`django-admin startproject winsdompets`

You can refer to this question to [ensure your django-admin path is one of your environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23915839/11607969).

By the way, to avoid those environmental issues in Mac or other platform, you can try to use [pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage your Django environment.

The following are instructions for Mac users.

```
# path/to/your/project/directory
brew install pipenv 
# It will create a new env and open a terminal shell, or open an existing env if there are pip settings files 
pipenv shell
pip install Django
django-admin startproject winsdompets
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you can follow Flux's comment to run your command without .py in [django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project).

Comment: I still get this error can't open file 'django-admin': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Might try to use bash rather than zsh and then install Django to start your project again? 
[Change from zsh to bash](https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/)

Comment: Also tried python3 /Users/fatgezimbela/Desktop/ django-admin.py startproject wisdompets
/usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/Users/fatgezimbela/Desktop/'

Comment: Try to [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23915839/11607969) to check your PATH.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209123/discussion-between-jun-zhou-and-fatgezim-bela).

Comment: This fixed it, took like 6 goes and all of the sugestions above and switching from bash to zsh , but it works now. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0Kwz-zE244

Comment: Well done, I also met this issue previously. So, whenever this is a new machine, I will ensure I have installed python3 and pip3 and removed python2(or make alias python=python3). Then I will just create pipenv environment under python3 to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should activate the python environment before you create a project.
1. check the path of "django-admin"

```
sudo find / -name "django-admin"
```

2.check the path of "python"

```
which python
```

If the paths are different, activate python in the directory of "django-admin".
eg. the path of "django-admin" is /var/www/env/bin/djang-admin

```
source /var/www/env/bin/activate
```