# Not able to install Django on Mac OS. Not sure what to do

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos, terminal

Im Super lost and frustrated. Not sure what to do next. Please someone help me, this si the last question I asked. I tried all of the options an none worked.

[Django Start project not working after install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555515/django-start-project-not-working-after-install/60555686#60555686)

```
    fatgezimbela@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % pip3 install django==3.0.3                                 
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: django==3.0.3 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from django==3.0.3) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from django==3.0.3) (3.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from django==3.0.3) (2019.3)

fatgezimbela@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3 django-admin startproject wisdompets              
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file 'django-admin': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

fatgezimbela@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3 django-admin.py startproject wisdompets
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

fatgezimbela@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % django-admin startproject wisdompets              
zsh: command not found: django-admin

fatgezimbela@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % django-admin startproject foo
zsh: command not found: django-admin

fatgezimbela@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3 django-admin startproject winsdompets
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file 'django-admin': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `python3 xxx` actually tries to execute xxx file with Python3. As the file `django-admin` is not in your current folder, it raises an error.

It seems that `django-admin` is not in your path. As written in [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/), you can try to invoke `django-admin` with `python3 -m django startproject wisdompets`. Maybe restarting your shell can also add `django-admin` to your path.